# `http_proxy` not showing up with `printenv` on WSL

Tags: bash, proxy, environment-variables, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am having trouble getting pip to work behind a corporate firewall. I added the http and https proxies to my `/etc/environment` file, and if I execute `echo "$HTTP_PROXY"` it prints the right thing. However, if I execute `env` or `printenv` none of the proxy variables show up. I think this is why `pip` is failing too. Any insight would be appreciated. My `/etc/environment` file looks like

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
http_proxy="http://<stuff>.<stuff>.org:80"
HTTP_PROXY="http://<stuff>.<stuff>.org:80"
https_proxy="https://<stuff>.<stuff>.org:443"
HTTPS_PROXY="https://<stuff>.<stuff>.org:443"
```

And I added the same lines to my `~/.bashrc` file as well.

Comment: Did you login again after adding to `/etc/environment`? Did you use `export` when adding to `~/.bashrc`?

Comment: I didn't use export in the `.bashrc` file. Thanks for pointing that out. Also, I'm not sure I have logged in again either. I restarted my whole computer, but I am running windows subsystem for Linux (sadface) and it doesn't ask for my credentials on start up, so maybe something funny is going on there.

Comment: adding the "export" did the trick! Thank you!

Comment: I don't know if WSL uses the usual login mechanisms, it probably doesn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

WSL doesn't use the PAM stack when starting a shell (login or not), so  PAM-based things fail:

- `/etc/environment` and `~/.pam_environment`, read by `pam_env`, don't apply ([WSL #1405](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1405))
- default umask from `pam_umask` isn't set ([WSL #352](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/352))
- limits from `pam_limits` ([WSL #1576](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1576))

---

Specifically for environment settings, it might be simplest to just add those to `.profile` (if running login shells) or `.bashrc`, with `export`.

---

Generally, there doesn't seem to be a simple solution.

You could log in again as your user:

```
sudo -iu "$USER"
su - "$USER"
```

These should load the PAM configuration in `/etc/pam.d/sudo` or `/etc/pam.d/su` respectively. But these are slightly different from each other, and also different from `/etc/pam.d/sshd` or `/etc/pam.d/lightdm`, so not everything would be the same as if you logged into an actual Ubuntu system via the GUI or SSH.

(Both `sudo` and `su` would ask for passwords, but both can be configured to not ask for passwords.)

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're having as due to ["bash not picking up /etc/environment"](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1405#issuecomment-1806750998) in WSL. I stumbled upon it and it's nasty. What's more nasty is that it's a 7 years old issue, as of writing, still not solved. I'm copying my workaround from the issue, for whoever is landing here:

---

To celebrate  the 7 years anniversary of this issue in 10 days, I present you my workaround, based on @smaktacular 's one, that combines `/etc/environment` & your current `$PATH` set elsewhere (eg Windows Paths set by WSL, other `export PATH=` in `.bashrc`/`.zshrc` etc):

At the end of your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` add the following:

```
export PATH_TEMP=$PATH
while read line; do export $line; done < /etc/environment
# $PATH now is "/some/paths:/..." but we need to omit first & last chars (the quotes)
export PATH=$PATH_TEMP:${PATH:1:${#PATH}-2}
unset PATH_TEMP
```

Done - It took me a bit more than 7 minutes, it will take you a bit more than 7 seconds.

Happy 7 years anniversary!

PS:> Make sure you have a newline at the end of /etc/environment otherwise read line breaks ;-)