# Environment Variables not working in WSL

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal, bashrc, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have used the commands

```
export http_proxy=address:port
```

and

```
export https_proxy=address:port
```

to set http and https proxy in bash in WSL. But every time I open bash, the environment variables are becoming empty. I tried setting up these variables in `/etc/environment` and `~/.bashrc` too.

I am using `bash.exe` command in cmd promt to open bash.

Comment: At least partially related I think: [`http_proxy` not showing up with `printenv` on WSL](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1046253/http-proxy-not-showing-up-with-printenv-on-wsl)

Answer (score -1):

If you use `export`, you can only use the environment variables on that terminal session. Else, you have to add it to `/etc/enviroment`.

But if you aren't logged in as root, you can't use it. You should change the permissions of the file.